# How can I put a constant prefix in front of every new line in Vim as I type?

Tags: vim

Ok, this is a rather complicated desire. It stems from the fact that most of my Fortran lines contain a "call" statement, and I am tired of typing call, call, call, call...

What I would like to have is the following:

- every time I press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, the next line has a "call " string added automatically in front.
- if I press tab, the tab is added *in front* of the string call (so that I can indent)
- if I am at the beginning of the line, and I press backspace once, it will remove the "call " entry, but leave the tabs. Similarly, it would be nice if it could remove automatically the entry if I type "if ", "do ", "enddo" and all the related

Does anything like this already exists, is possible, and what are some hints or similar scripts I can take from?

For example, in the C-style comment, every time I press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, an asterisk is added automatically at the beginning of the line. Where is the code that does that (I assume it's plugin functionality, not hardcoded in Vim)?

Comment: `:help eval` `:help usr_41.txt` will help you.

Answer (score 3):

I followed your hint about C comments and came up with this:

```
:set formatoptions+=ro
:set comments+=s:call,m:call,e:call
```

If a line starts with 'call', this should automatically prepend consecutive lines with the same text.  It only works if previous line contained 'call', and 'call' isn't deleted on keywords you specified.  Feel free to play with those options, maybe you'll customize it to youtsr liking.

For indenting use <kbd>>></kbd> in normal mode or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> in insert mode. To delete 'call' at the beginning of the line use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd> instead of <kbd>Backspace</kbd>.

Alternatively you could use abbreviations to speed up your typing:

```
:iab ,, call
```

Comment: I don't want to use abbreviations, because then I tend to develop muscular memory I transfer to other languages. I occasionally type call when I am coding in python.

Comment: very nice, pragmatic and complete

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, when there is need of changing behaviour of `<CR>` and `<BS>`, it means that something is wrong, or will be wrong sooner or later because there are many edge cases.

One of the biggest problems I found is that I cannot guess if cursor was in first or second column inside functions, and it's a main point to know to be able to process correctly tabs and backspaces. But here you have a start. I have not thoroughly tested it because it is a mess. I don't recommend it, **myki**'s approach is much better in my opinion.

Add this well commented code to your `vimrc` file and test it.

```
"" When pressed 'return' in insert mode:
"" <Esc>: Exit from Insert Mode to Normal Mode.
"" o: Add a new line below the current one and set Insert Mode.
"" call <Esc>: Write literal 'call ' and exit from Insert Mode.
"" A: Set cursor at end of line and enter Insert Mode to begin writting.
inoremap <cr> <Esc>ocall <Esc>A

function! SpecialTab()

    "" Get cursor position.
    let cursor_pos = getpos('.')

    "" If line is empty, insert a tab, update current position and finish
    let line_len = strlen( getline( line('.') ) ) 
    if empty( getline( line('.') ) ) || line_len == 1
        s/\%#/\t/   
        let cursor_pos[2] += 1
        call setpos( '.', cursor_pos )
        return
    endif

    "" Search for a line beginning with 'call', omitting spaces. If found
    "" insert a tab at the beginning of line.
    if match( getline( line('.') ), "\s*call" ) != -1
        s/^/\t/
    else
        "" Insert a normal tab in current cursor position. I cannot use
        "" the regular <Tab> command because function would entry in a 
        "" infinite recursion due to the mapping.
        s/\%#\(.\)/\1\t/
    endif

    "" Set cursor column in the character it was before adding tab character.
    let cursor_pos[2] += 2
    call setpos( '.', cursor_pos )
endfunction

"" Map the tab character.
inoremap <Tab> <Esc>:call SpecialTab()<cr>:startinsert<cr>

function! SpecialBackspace()
    "" Do nothing if line is empty.
    if empty( getline( line('.') ) ) 
        return
    endif

    "" Get cursor position.
    let cursor_pos = getpos( '.' )

    "" If cursor is not in first column press 'delete' button and done.
    if col('.') > 1 
        execute "normal \<Del>"
        return
    endif

    "" Search for 'call' string. If found delete it and set cursor in
    "" previous position.
    if match( getline( line('.') ), "\s*call" ) != -1
        s/call//
        let cursor_pos[2] = 1 
        call setpos( '.', cursor_pos )
        return
    endif

    "" A line with one character is a special case. I delete the complete
    "" line.
    let line_len = strlen( getline( line('.') ) )
    if line_len == 1
        s/^.*$//
        return
    endif

    "" If cursor is in first column, delete character. Messy behavior, I
    "" think :-/
    if col('.') == 1
        s/^.//
    endif
endfunction

"" Map the 'backspace' character.
inoremap <BS> <Esc>:call SpecialBackspace()<cr>:startinsert<cr>
```